# Linux : Watchdog always busy

Tags: linux, watchdog

I can"t use the device /dev/watchdog because something using it.

```
echo 1 > /dev/watchdog -> Ressource busy
```

Tests (as root) :

```
ls 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root  10, 130 27 juil. 12:34 /dev/watchdog
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 251,   0 27 juil. 12:34 /dev/watchdog0

lsof /dev/watchdog
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   40w   CHR 10,130      0t0 8206 /dev/watchdog


fuser -v /dev/watchdog
                     UTIL.       PID ACCÈS  COMMANDE
/dev/watchdog:       root          1 F.... systemd
```

I have no ideas why i can't access to this device.

Kernel : 4.11
Driver : iTCO_wdt and softdog -> same behavior

Thx for your help.

Comment: Is there a systemd watchdog service running?

Comment: No. systemctl | grep running didn't display a watchdog service.

Comment: But I do have a [watchdogd] in the process list (PID 52)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the systemd watchdog inside the configuration file : /etc/systemd/system.conf worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why the 'device or resource busy' error

The issue I found was that systemd and wd_keepalive seemed to be using the watchdog resource per fuser output:

```
>sudo fuser -v /dev/watchdog
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/watchdog:       root      15087 F.... wd_keepalive
```

and

```
>sudo fuser -v /dev/watchdog
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/watchdog:       root          1 F.... systemd
```

#### Fix the Busy Error

I removed watchdog timer references from `/etc/systemd/system.conf` to get rid of the busy issue on the `systemd` busy system.

If you're feeling bold, you can kill -9 your wd_keepalive PID, then echo your character toward the `/dev/watchdog` device, if you want to manually control the watchdog.  I prefer just letting the daemon do its thing.

#### Watchdog setup that works on Pi running Stretch 12/17/18

Unlike some other suggestions on SO and the net, I did not need to install watchdog as a device on the Pi e.g. in `/boot/config.txt`. Nor did I need to call any services other than via systemctl.  I just ran

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
sudo update-rc.d watchdog defaults
```

Then to configure watchdog I put these lines in `/etc/watchdog.conf`

```
watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog

# Set default Timeout
watchdog-timeout         = 14
```

#### Running Watchdog

Then the only thing I needed to do to use watchdog was call this from my application, which I run after bootup:

```
sudo systemctl stop watchdog
sudo systemctl enable watchdog
sudo systemctl start watchdog
sudo systemctl -l status watchdog
```